# Docker task ARG and LABEL commands extremely slow

Tags: docker, azure-pipelines

We use the Azure DevOps Docker task to buildAndPush a docker image from a Dockerfile.
The Dockerfile contains a number of ARG lines to accept arguments for a subsequent task and Azure DevOps itself set a number of LABELs. Both of these commands take a huge amount of time per ARG and LABEL command. Afterwards in the logs, once a build completes and the image is pushed to DockerHub, the layerId is indicated as missing.

Example from the Dockerfile:

```
ARG RELAYHOST=smtp
ARG SMTPPORT=25
ARG AUTO_SYNC=true
ARG CERTIFICATE=none
ARG CERTIFICATE_KEY=none
ARG HTTPS=true
ARG TZ=Etc/UTC
ARG SSHD=false
```

During build where each ARG Step takes like a minute:

```
Step 29/46 : ARG CERTIFICATE_KEY=none
 ---> Running in 32653321baf7
Removing intermediate container 32653321baf7
 ---> ab03fb6241b6
Step 30/46 : ARG HTTPS=true
 ---> Running in 5f6728d9ed0a
Removing intermediate container 5f6728d9ed0a
 ---> 372e9283e82e
Step 31/46 : ARG TZ=Etc/UTC
 ---> Running in 64145050b3b3
```

Result:

```
createdAt:2022-04-27T15:21:31Z; layerSize:0B; createdBy:ARG SSHD=false; layerId:<missing>
createdAt:2022-04-27T15:21:31Z; layerSize:0B; createdBy:ARG TZ=Etc/UTC; layerId:<missing>
createdAt:2022-04-27T15:21:31Z; layerSize:0B; createdBy:ARG HTTPS=true; layerId:<missing>
createdAt:2022-04-27T15:21:31Z; layerSize:0B; createdBy:ARG CERTIFICATE_KEY=none; layerId:<missing>
createdAt:2022-04-27T15:21:31Z; layerSize:0B; createdBy:ARG CERTIFICATE=none; layerId:<missing>
createdAt:2022-04-27T15:21:31Z; layerSize:0B; createdBy:ARG AUTO_SYNC_ON_START=YES; layerId:<missing>
```

Would anyone be able to explain why building with ARG and LABEL is taking such a long time per line? I would expect the docker build task to fly over these quite quickly...

Thanks
Thomas

Comment: Am I missing something? It looks like the timestamps are all the same.

Comment: Yes, they are the timestamps when the final image is pushed, but the individual steps during the docker build take about a minute between each step

Comment: I also have this issue, the only solution I can think of is to hardcode the value...